# Random "namespace name 'Core' does not exist in namespace ' Tweetinvi"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, tweetinvi

I'm using the Tweetinvi C# Twitter API. It was working great until about 3 hours ago, when my solution (specifically one project) just stopped building.

The error is a normal Assembly/Reference missing error, but I can see the files listed in the "references" folder. If i refresh the project, the errors go away. Until i build, then they come back.

This is the same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825867/random-assembly-references-fail-are-you-missing-a-using-directive-or-an-assemb), but my project does not target the client profile, its targets .NET 4 (Project>Properties>Application>Target Framework, right?), like it did this morning, like it did yesterday.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the Tweetinvi package via Nuget. Removed the references and re-added manually. No change.

EDIT:
To keep the crazy up, if i go to the Object Browser, and view by Namespace, there is only {}Tweetinvi.Security. If i refresh the project, i get them ALL back. Until I build.

EDIT2:
One of the warnings i get on build.

> The primary reference "Tweetinvi, Version=0.9.3.3, Culture=neutral,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an
>   indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Threading.Tasks,
>   Version=2.5.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
>   which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework.
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove
>   the reference "Tweetinvi, Version=0.9.3.3, Culture=neutral,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a
>   framework version which contains "System.Threading.Tasks,
>   Version=2.5.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

Comment: Can you check to see if you've added a reference to your own project?

Comment: I don't believe I do, but how would I check that?

Comment: Check the references for your project, if you have the project name (of itself) listed as a reference, that's what I'm asking about. I doubt it as well, but I know that with a self-reference you will get spurious odd problems. Not sure the one you list is one of them, but worth a check.

Comment: Thats what I thought you meant, but I asked just to be sure. No it does not reference itself.

Comment: Visual studio... Is it possible to create a new project, add the package to that one and build? What happens?

Comment: Perhaps you already did this - but check for all dependencies versions of tweetinvi package. Maybe a version mismatch somewhere.

Comment: Created new project, moved offending class to it, added Tweetinvi via nuget, builds fine.

Comment: @llya, I figured Nuget would do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some more Goolging on the Error showing in EDIT2, I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618391/type-or-namespace-not-found-are-you-missing-assembly-reference-while-all-refer), and specifically the [answer by fahadash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23619041). This fixed my issue. I had changed these properties in the GUI, but it wasn't until I went and did it manually (With Sublime Text), that it took effect.

Here is a copy of fahadash's answer

> I found [this Blog post from Nansen](http://blog.nansen.com/2012/09/possible-solution-to-build-warning.html) and I applied the fix and got my
>   issue resolved.
>
> Summary of the solution: Edit the csproj file in XML editor and find
>   the elements for the references that are troubling you and add the
>   following child element to those.
>
> `<SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>`
>
> Make sure the word True is only first letter uppercase (True, not true
>   or TRUE).
>
> Save and reload the project in VS and build it.